# How to store the Value of Object type of a KStream in a Hashmap?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, hashmap, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a KStream object like `KStream<String, Object>`. 
I want to fetch the value of the Object in a HashMap and store it as a value after processing in a different KStream?

For instance,

KStream key = "First"

KStream value = {id=1, name="abc" age=12}

Desired result :
HashMap hm ={id=1, name="abc" age=12}

Comment: Something seems to be missing in your json snippet. Otherwise do you mean that the KStream value alone produces both the key and the value for the HashMap?

Comment: Yes, the Json contains a java object so i has both key and value for the hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some conceptual miss-understanding.

A `KStream` is a logical abstraction over a topic (and thus all records in it). It allows you to processed those records one-by-one. For example, you can do:

```java
KStream stream = builder.stream(...);
stream.foreach((k, v) -> { /* your processing logic */});
```

> I want to fetch the value of the Object in a HashMap

It seems you want to have a `HashMap` in the same scope as the `KStream`. 
However, you cannot access any record from "outside" but only by applying operators (like `foreach()` as shown in the example above) to a `KStream` to transform one `KStream` into a new `KStream.

> and store it as a value after processing in a different KStream

Note sure what that mean. You can transform one `KStream` into a new `KStream` by applying an operator on it. For example:

```java
KStream result = kstream.map(...);
```

This program will execute the function you pass into `map()` for each record in `kstream` and append the result record of you map function to `result`. Ie, `map()` transforms each input record into a new output record.

Note that when you define your processing, you basically specify a data flow program that is executed continuously after you call `KafkaStreams#start()`.